# Textbox.Text last value before the change?

Tags: c#

i am having trouble with the following code:
everything is working properly, 
what i wanna do the following thing,

when the user is changing the textbox, if it passed all the conditions (u can see my code)
it will fire up a DB query that will update a row.
now in order to fire this query i need the older value of this textbox, before the change, now how i may do it without addind a Variable to store its old value each textbox, i have few of those.

is there any event that remmber the old value?

thanks.

```
    private void txt1stRoom_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt1stRoom.Text == txt1stRoomHuman.Text || txt1stRoom.Text == txt2ndRoom.Text || txt1stRoom.Text == txt3rdRoom.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Error - Cannot Use Same Monster");
        else if (txt1stRoom.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + serverTbx.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbNameTbx.Text + ";User ID=" + dbUserTbx.Text + ";Password='" + dbPassTbx.Text + "';");
            m_daoManager.init(cn);
            string mobName = m_daoManager.getMonsterName(txt1stRoom.Text);
            m_daoManager.close(cn);
            if (mobName != string.Empty)
            {
                //
                var result1 = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure u want to change " +lblOrc.Text + "to "+ mobName+ " , Please Notice - This will apply the changes to your database aswell!","Are You Sure?, Please Confirm this Change!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (result1 == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    m_daoManager.init(cn);
                    foreach (int zoneID in Maps.Keys)
                    {
m_daoManager.updateMonstersByZone(BeforeChangetxt1stRoom.Text, AfterChangetxt1stRoom.text, zoneID);
                    }
                    m_daoManager.close(cn);
                    lblOrc.Text = mobName;
                    lblOrc.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.lblOrc1 = lblOrc.Text;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.lblOrc1Color = lblOrc.ForeColor;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Monster Found Under this ID");
                txt1stRoom.Text = string.Empty;
                lblOrc.Text = "Enter Mob ID";
                lblOrc.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                Properties.Settings.Default.lblOrc1 = lblOrc.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.lblOrc1Color = lblOrc.ForeColor;
            }
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would advice you to create and store the ID ([primay key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx)) of you database object, which your TextBox property refers to. By doing this, you would be able to make the UPDATE of you object by the ID, but not by the last TextBox value.

Another way - is to organize your logic by means of [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134), so that you would change your model object and these changes reflect on your database side.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the Tag property of your TextBox's. Store the "old" value whenever you feel it's appropriate (maybe after first using it as "new").